# Передать массив в JavaScript

Tags: массивы, asp.net-mvc, javascript

Здравствуйте.
На странице приходится динамически создавать несколько comboBox'ов.
Получать содержимое списков для них ajax-запросами нет необходимости. Данные статичны.
Соответственно создаю `ComboBox`'ы с помощью `jQuery`. Вопрос: как передать данные из контроллера в `javascript`?

В контроллере, например, размещаю следующий код:

```
ViewBag.MyArray = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Name");
```

В представлении нужно сделать так, чтоб в сгенерированной странице массив `javascript` имел значения из ViewBag.MyArray.

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
// в контроллере:  
ViewBag.MyArray = new SelectList(new[]
                      {
                          new { Id = 1, Name = "John Smith" },
                          new { Id = 2, Name = "John Snow" }
                      }, "Id", "Name");

// js 
var myarr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.MyArray))
$.each(myarr,
  function (num, item) {    
      $('#mySelect').append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
  });

// html 
<select id='mySelect'></select>
```

Впрочем, если нужно лишь заполнить из ViewBag выпадающий список, то все это можно сделать куда проще:

```
@SelectExtensions.DropDownList(Html, "mySecondSelect", ViewBag.MyArray)
```